# Why this only works with "!important"?

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code, that it refuses to work without the `!important` (which I never want to use, because I know there is always a way to do without it).

The interesting thing is that the CSS line is after everything else (and as far as I know, this should overwrite the other stuff)

live demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRErA/)

**HTML Structure:**

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="box">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#body{
    padding:18px 35px;
}

#body p{
    margin-bottom:18px;
}

.box{
    background:#ddd;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px;
}

.box p{
    margin:0;/*works with !important*/
}
```

Comment: I managed to make it work by adding `#body` before the `.box p`, These kind of things make me think I will never master CSS....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the ID of #body p is a more specific selector than the class of .box p.  The important simply overrides that cascade.

Comment: So you are saying the CSS is parsed like: execute CSS in least-specific/most- specific (order doesn't matter with the only exception when two or more guys share the exact same path? (then the order will matter?)

Comment: Order only matters when they are equivalent in specificity.  .class { color: red; } .class { color: blue; } is order dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Matching p with #body has higher specificity than matching p with .box. Read the [specificity section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of the CSS spec for help. Try

```
#header .box p { margin: 0; }
```

The space between #header and .box is important.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#body p` has a greater specificity value. You can read more on generally how specificity values are calculated [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/).